# How to pass the Post Title as value?

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, title, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to pass the post title of a single post as value for 'terms':

```
<?php 
    $term = get_the_title();

    query_posts(array( 
        'post_type' => 'referenzen',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array (
                'taxonomy' => 'referenzen-kategorie',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => '{$term}',
            )
        ),
        'showposts' => 7 
    ) );  
?>
```

Explanation: the single post title corresponds to the terms of some Posts of the Custom Post Type 'referenzen', and there are several posts with the corresponding term for example: Design & Production --> I'm trying to pass the single Post Title "Design & Production" to 'terms' => 'Design & Production'.

Comment: simply remove `'{}'` 
ex:`'terms'=>$term`

Comment: Thank you, you helped me solving this problem!

Comment: And what else happens with that code?

Comment: **Note**: Don't update your question's code with the solution, it makes it much harder for anybody with a similar problem to correlate the problem and solution

Answer (score 0):

The issue in the above code was passing post title instead of post slug in the terms field. You can get the post slug using the global $post variable which contains the complete post object array

```
<?php
global $post;
$term = $post->post_name;

query_posts(array( 
    'post_type' => 'referenzen',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array (
            'taxonomy' => 'referenzen-kategorie',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array($term),
        )
    ),
    'showposts' => 7 
) );  
?>
```

Comment: The issue in the above code was passing post title instead of post slug in the terms field. You can get the post slug using the global $post variable which contains the complete post object array.

Comment: Please add all such explanation to the answer itself by editing it, not to the comment section